# Sun JAX-WS implementation picked instead of CXF one in Eclipse Virgo

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, eclipse-virgo

I have very obvious problem, but still did not found solution to it. I have OSGI bundle which uses Apache CXF for Client. Problem is, then i deploy application i get this error:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to 
org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
```

As far as i understand, this error occurs because of the wrong JAX-WS implementation was loaded in Classpath. The question is:  how i can ensure what CXF implementation is loaded?

Everything works fine in Apache Felix, i have feeling this has something to with Virgo loading a lot more bundles then Felix by default.

I use *cxf-2.6.0.jar* instead of *cfx-dosgi-ri* bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this problem by adding apache servicemix jaxws-api to Virgo repository. Then i created plan for my bundles, and made jaxws-api start before *cxf-2.6.0.jar* bundle.